# Alternative in-app-purchase methods for Android

Tags: android, paypal, in-app-purchase, fortumo

I want to use an alternative way for in-app purchases in my Android application such as [Fortumo](http://fortumo.com/) or [PayPal libraries](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/gs_MPL/). Don't they violate Android Developers Terms of Services? Or will it cause the suspending of my developer account?

Can I also sell electronic currencies in my application using Android native In-App-Purchase?

Answer (score 5):

> In-app purchases: Developers offering virtual goods or currencies
>   within a game downloaded from Google Play must use Google Play's
>   in-app billing service as the method of payment. Developers offering
>   additional content, services or functionality within another category
>   of app downloaded from Google Play must use Google Play's in-app
>   billing service as the method of payment, except:
>
> where payment is primarily for physical goods or services (e.g., buying movie tickets,
>   or buying a publication where the price also includes a hard copy
>   subscription);
>   or where payment is for digital content or goods that
>   may be consumed outside of the app itself (e.g., buying songs that can
>   be played on other music players).
>
> Developers must not mislead users about the apps they are selling nor
>   about any in-app services, goods, content or functionality they are
>   selling. If your product description on Google Play refers to in-app
>   features to which a specific or additional charge applies, your
>   description must clearly notify users that payment is required to
>   access those features.

Source: https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html

Comment: To summarize a bit: if what you're selling is a change within the app, or access to an app, then you must use Google's payment service. If what you're selling can be made available outside the app -- a physical good, a music file, an epub file, etc. -- then you are allowed to use a different payment method to do this, assuming you don't violate any other terms.

Comment: @LorneLaliberte, If user is not purchasing from the app, but if they can purchase from website outside of application. Is this the violation of the terms?

Comment: @LorneLaliberte it depends on WHAT are they purchasing. If they are paying to remove ads (from a website) it's a violation. If they are paying for something accessible outside the app it's NOT a violation

Answer (score 2):

Consult a lawyer, not SO. IANL, but the Market agreement states that

> All fees received by Developers for Products distributed via the
>   Market must be processed by the Market's Payment Processor.

AFAIK, the only authorized payment processor is Google Checkout/Wallet, so you decide whether using PayPal violates the agreement.

Answer (score 0):

Direct in-app payment would violate Google's terms. However there are a large number of developers (e.g., KKBox) which do not want to pay Google 30% split. What they do is essential setting up a login page with passcode. On the other hand, they sell those passcode as pay-as-you-go or subscription. I believe this does not violate the terms of Google.

Comment: This is not clear. KKBox is providing musics and as per the terms any digital content that can be used out-side of app is already out of the violation terms.

Comment: Actually real question is; is there any way to bypass google in-app purchase if I setup purchase functionality on my product webpage? Purchase there can be synced to my app without any issue. I believe that is not the violation if I am not purchasing from the app.