# In-app billing without publishing to Google play Store

Tags: google-play, in-app-billing

Our app has been lucky enough to be pre-installed on some phones but it has in-app purchases. We have some customization so we don’t want it to appear in the Play store.  How do I make that work with Google Play Billing services, but not have it show up in the Play store?

Comment: I imagine that your app would have to go through the screening process and be in the Google Play store before they allow you to make use of any of their services. Especially any type of payment services.

Answer (score 0):

As per official [docs](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html)

> To test in-app billing, you need to publish your app to an alpha or
>   beta channel in Google Play.

You will have to publish to play store. However you can either publish it publicly or to a private channel. If your app is built for enterprise, you can publish it using a private channel. Here's more about it:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en
That ways your app wont be public on play store and you may still be able to implement in app purchase - not sure about it yet but you may want to check.
You may also check publishing to beta/alpha channels or trying out an alternative payment solution based on what you plan to sell as described here
[Alternative in-app-purchase methods for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874052/alternative-in-app-purchase-methods-for-android)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, the private channel does not look to be the right solution for us as it looks to be restricted to people we choose to be added to the channel.

Comment: We have been using the Alpha and Beta channels for testing, but with the new Opt-In feature it limits us to, once again, knowing the people who will be using the application.

Comment: ok then I think you shouldn't use in-app payment solution as it depends on installs from a google play link restricted to set of users that you add to channel